# Realtime color picker hsv to hex string?

Tags: javascript, colors, hex, draggable, hsv

What I need is a realtime color picker(realtime as in color is generated while the controls are still being dragged and not upon releasing them) that uses some sort of draggable control thingys that one can drag up and down to determine hue saturation and value. The hsv from the draggable thingys should then be converted to a hex string like "#000000". Is this possible? If so, how?

Comment: I have tried searching google for a hsv to hex converter sourcecode, but without success. If I had one I could simply make some draggable thingys myself and then use the converter function to generate my hex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at

- http://www.dematte.at/colorPicker/ and
- http://www.eyecon.ro/colorpicker/

both should fit your requirements.

Regards,

STEFAN

Comment: Those may be cool and everything, but I'd prefer something that does not use plugins or similar. Something like a single function or summin.

Comment: Couldn't find anything better, so I guess your suggestions are best... Thank you very much